# SharePoint 2013 Timeline Displays time only

Tags: timeline

In every Timeline example I have seen, the Timeline displays with the month and day, as below
[image]

In my task list, I only see hours
[image]

I can't figure out how to change what is displayed to the month/day format. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding an additional task to your timeline that has a different end/due date and set a start date that is on a different day. When I tried adding just a single task to my Task List with the start and due date on the same day, the timeline only shows hours like yours because that is the only task in the list so there is no need to span multiple days. But if I add another task to the timeline for a different date it expands the timescale automatically.

Also, if you click the Timeline then a **Timeline** option becomes available in the top menu (next to Task and List). This menu allows you to make some minor adjustments to the Timeline, Timescale, and the way events are shown.

[image]

Comment: Dangit. I should have realized that. Thanks for the advice. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [this article](http://ppmworks.com/change-timescale-of-sharepoint-timeline-view/), there is no way to modify the timescale of timeline view.

The timescale on the timeline depends on the tasks' dates and durations.

You could use a Calendar View instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I still don't understand why my timeline displays hours, and just every other timeline I have ever seen, displays month/day. I know I'm missing something. I just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Timescale adjusts automatically depending on your tasks, apparently you have just one task and it's for today, try creating more tasks, longer than 1 day duration and the timescale should change :)